# Changing Ionic React core files doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, ionic5

I am using Ionic React (version 5.0.4), and changed the "reorder-group.js" file in the following path, in order to add some features to the `<IonReorderGroup>` tag:

> MyProject\node_modules@ionic\core\dist\collection\components\reorder-group\reorder-group.js

However, when I serve the app (`npm run start`) or build it (`npm run build`) there is no change.

Why is it happening and how can I solve it? (maybe it has something to do with cache files or anything similar?)

Thanks in advance!